# Cloud Foundry - log4j2 - Incorporate App URI in log

Tags: java, log4j2, cloud-foundry

We are logging to splunk (via logreggator) in Cloud Foundry. We are using log4j2 via slf4j.

We are already specifying the instance UID and index in the log4j2 config:

```
<Console ...>
  ...
  <KeyValuePair key="@instanceGUID" value="${env:CF_INSTANCE_GUID:-unknown}" />
  ...
</Console>
```

Is there any way to do something similar for the space/route/pool?
Ideally we would love to be able to include @space with values like dev, qa, uat etc... and pool: emea1, gb2 etc...

At the most basic capturing the route(s) in the log would be enough.

Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull the space name from `VCAP_APPLICATION`. Ex: `echo $VCAP_APPLICATION | jq .space_name`.

You can also get the URI/Routes, but there can be multiple so I'm not sure exactly what you'd want to log. Ex: `echo $VCAP_APPLICATION | jq '.uris | first'` would get you the first one. If you don't bind multiple routes to your apps, maybe that's good enough...

I don't know what you mean by pool. If you're referring to the Cell, I don't know of a way to get that. The best you can do is the Cell's IP, which is `CF_INSTANCE_IP`.

You can always add your own env variables as well, to incorporate more information into your logs.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I can read the URIs in app code alright but I was hoping for a way to take advantage of the `${env:xxx}` processing built into log4j2.
Pool is just a term for the geo region specifier in the url.

Comment: You can add a `.profile` script to the root of your app. This script will run prior to your app. You can do something like `APP_URL=$(echo $VCAP_APPLICATION | jq '.uris | first')` in that script. That will set an env variable `APP_URL`, which you could access from your config file, `${env:APP_URL}`.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Marked your answer as the solution.